# Korean Filenames are shown like ''$'\355\225\234\352\270\200''.'txt' in iTerm2 on OSX HighSierra

Tags: terminal, zsh, korean

From 2 days ago, when I enter `ls` in iTerm2(also default terminal app),
directories I created are shown like `'0. PCR'`, and Korean filenames are 
shown as `''$'\355\225\234\352\270\200''.txt'`.

[image]

In finder windows, all filenames are correctly shown in Korean letters

[image]

but in terminal, Korean files are shown like above. I use zsh and oh-my-zsh and I've tried to find similar issues in internet but I cannot find same case. 
Are there anybody who can describe why this happen and how to fix?

Comment: `ls` in my Debian prints this filename in Korean (my `LANG` is `pl_PL.UTF-8`). However `LC_ALL=C ls --quoting-style=shell-escape` replicates the issue.

Comment: Is this problem occurring locally, or are you connecting to a non-macOS system via SSH?

Comment: grawity: it happened on my MacBook Pro. Thanks a lot for your trying to help ^^

Comment: Kamil : Based on your explanation, I set some locale info on my .zshrc and .inputrc .. after that, the broken Korean filenames are fixed. but this time, "LS_COLOR" doesn't work. Basically I use OMZsh.. I think some config settings are broken after deleting zsh-templates-osx due to updating errors using MacPorts. Thanks a lot ! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it after adding two things.

1. in my `~/.zshrc`

   ```
   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
   ```
2. in my `~/.inputrc`

   ```
   set meta-flag on
   set input-meta on
   set output-meta on
   set convert-meta off
   ```

Thank you Kamil and Grawity for your kind comments.